# Can't escape characters in pug/jade

Tags: html, pug, templating-engine

I'm trying to escape special characters in pug/jade but it keeps giving me errors.

I tried !{}, #[] and #[!] but non of these options allow me to use "(" character.

```
p.
   !{(} Edit !{>} Preferences !{>} Media !{&}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to have Pug compile to HTML that looks something like this:

```
<p>(Edit > Preferences > Media & Lorem Ipsum)</p>
```

You can just write this Pug:

```
p (Edit > Preferences > Media & Lorem Ipsum)
```

Or this:

```
p.
  (Edit > Preferences > Media & Lorem Ipsum)
```

You shouldn't need to escape special characters in plain text in Pug, unless they're HTML tags.

If the above doesn't work, there's something going on with how Pug is configured, and you'll need to ask a new question and include any error messages.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, for some reason I started trying to escape the characters.